# Run getline every time a file is modified

Tags: c++

What my program is doing currently is reading a text file and then displaying the contents on screen. What I want it to do, read the file every time it is changed and then refresh the screen and show the new file contents. I tried to implement  a loop, but got an exception error when attempting to run. Here is my current setup with the loop:

```
    void number(HWND hwnd){
    HANDLE dwChangeHandles[2];
    char path[250];
    ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%\\\ECDisplay\\", path, 250);
    char versionpath[250];
    ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%\\\ECDisplay\\nursery.txt", 
    versionpath, 250);
    std::ifstream file(versionpath);
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(file, str)){
        nurserynumber = str;
        file.close();
    }
    dwChangeHandles[0] = FindFirstChangeNotification(
        path,                         // directory to watch 
        FALSE,                         // do not watch subtree 
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE); // watch file name changes 

    if (dwChangeHandles[0] == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {

    }
    else{
        number(hwnd);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
The error I received originally:
Unhandled exception at 0x7789EA0B (ntdll.dll) in EC Display.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x778D4270).

**EDIT 2**
Here's my current code:

```
void number(HWND hwnd){
    HANDLE dwChangeHandles[2];
    char path[250];
    ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%\\\ECDisplay\\", path, 250);
    char versionpath[250];
    ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%\\\ECDisplay\\nursery.txt", 
    versionpath, 250);
    std::ifstream file(versionpath);
    std::string str;
    dwChangeHandles[0] = FindFirstChangeNotification(
        path,                         // directory to watch 
        FALSE,                         // do not watch subtree 
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE); // watch file name changes 
    do{
    while (std::getline(file, str)){
        nurserynumber = str;    
    }

    } while (dwChangeHandles[0] != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
}
```

Comment: Not enough information to help find the crash, but closing the file in the `while(getline)` loop isn't going to do you much good.

Comment: If you read the [`FindFirstChangeNotification` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417(v=vs.85).aspx) you'll see you need to use "wait function" on the returned handle to get any kind of utility out of this.

Answer (score 2):

At least two things are likely to cause your crash, but without additional information we can only guess.

You close the file descriptor in a loop:

```
while (std::getline(file, str)) {
    ...
    file.close();
}
```

This seems really wrong in numerous ways.

It seems more likely that you want

```
if (!file.good()) {
    // handle error
    return;
}
if (!std::getline(file, str)) {
    // didn't read anything, if we care:
    return;
}
```

And second, you appear to be using recursion.

Towards the end of the function, you call the function with the same parameter is was invoked with rather than just performing a loop:

```
if (dwChangeHandles[0] == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
}
else{
    number(hwnd);
}
```

If the file isn't open, you do some error handling, but otherwise, you call the function again. Each call is going to use additional stack and eventually you're going to run out of stack and crash.

You should probably refactor the code to use a loop. For example, you could make it a

```
do {
    // ...
} while (dwChangeHandles[0] != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
```

loop around the entire inside of the function.

All the variables you declared in the function require stack space per call, so each time it calls itself it uses more and more stack. The variables in previous calls won't go out of scope until one of the calls returns and the stack unwinds.

Comment: After doing that my window doesn't open. There aren't any errors, but I call this function while the program is starting, now the program keeps running, but no window displays.

Comment: "after doing that" doesn't actually tell me what you did, I would suggest you post your modified code at the end of your initial question (add a "--- EDIT ---" and then post the code). If you want help fast, you should post an MVCE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: *"`getline` returns a reference to the string"* - not so - it returns a reference to the (if)streamargument: it's appropriate to check that to see if the string was read successfully: you've removed that in your `std::getline(file, str); if (str.empty()) {` rewrite.  Still, you're right that `file.close()` shouldn't be there - it means only the first line is ever read, and if that's what's wanted there's no reason to use a `while` loop.

Comment: @dogger20011 Ok, not sure how much of your code you are posting, but all `FindFirstChangeNotification` does is create a listener. You have to actually wait for and retrieve the notifications. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You close the file after reading 1 line:

```
while (std::getline(file, str)){
    nurserynumber = str;
    file.close();  // ?????
}
```

So when you use getline again, file isn't a valid file stream anymore.
I think you want `file.close()` outside of the `while`, no?

Comment: ...but then it ends up with the last line in the file in both `nurserynumber` and `str`, which probably isn't wanted either: code's so broken it's impossible to reason about.

Comment: That too. But to solve the exception, this is the fix they're going to need.